# Returns the maximum atribute of one instance

Tags: python, class

I'm creating a class Program in which i want to define some methods. There will be atributes as first name, last name, genre and height.
Imagine i want to return the tallest male .

```
class Height () :

  def __init__ (self, f_name, l_name, genre, height) :
    self.f_name = f_name
    self.l_name = l_name
    self.genre = genre
    self.height = height

  def full_name (self) :
    return self.f_name + self.l_name

  def tallest_male (self) :
    .......

person1 = Height ("Namea", "Nameb", "male", 179)
person2 = Height ("Namec", "Named", "male", 189)
person3 = Height ("Namee", "Namef", "female", 167)
person4 = Height ("Nameg", "Nameh", "female", 159)
person5 = Height ("Namej", "Namek", "male", 171)
person6 = Height ("Nameu", "Name v", "male", 149)
```

The problem is that i don't know how to save all 6 persons in one variable in order to do something like this:

```
 def tallest_male (self) :
    for i in persons :
      if self.genre == "male" :
        return max (self.height)

persons = [person1, person2, person3, person4, person5, person6]
```

Comment: `persons_height = [person1.height, person2.height ....]`
`max(persons_height)`

Comment: i did not think about that but imagine i do that. How can i return the height and the correspondant person of that height?

Comment: `max(xrange(len(persons_height)), key = lambda x: persons_height[x])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your persons inside a list, and then you can easily manipulate this list to get what you want. For instance:

```
persons = []
persons.append(Height ("Namea", "Nameb", "male", 179))
persons.append(Height ("Namec", "Named", "male", 189))
...
```

Then you define a `tallest_male` function which takes in a list of `Height` variables. Here are 2 examples, take the one you understand best (or write your own one)

```
def tallest(persons):
  tallest_index = 0
  tallest_height = 0
  for i in range(len(persons)):
    if persons[i].genre == "male" and persons[i].height > tallest_height:
      tallest_index = i
      tallest_height = persons[i].height
  return persons[tallest_index]

def tallest2(persons):
  males = filter (persons, lambda p: p.genre == 'male') # thanks @Demi-Lune
  return max(males, key=lambda x: x.height)
```

Output:

```
print(tallest(persons).full_name()) # prints "NamecNamed"
print(tallest2(persons).full_name()) # prints "NamecNamed"
```

By the way, you may want to edit your `full_name` method so that there is a space between name and surname.

Comment: Since you're already using max and lambda, you could also use a filter : `males = filter (persons, lambda p: p.genre == 'male')`, instead of the list comprehension

Comment: @Demi-Lune You're completely right. I'm more used to list comprehensions so I used them, but your suggestion makes a bit more sense. I'll edit the code, thanks.

Comment: thank you so much for the effort you put on the answer. Very nice ideas thank you all